# Unable to send email using ssmtp from home computer

Tags: email, gmail

After opening the port and having no success, I disabled the belkin router completely. So now there is no firewall blocking traffic. However, I continue to get the following error:

```
ssmtp: Cannot open smtp.gmail:465
```

I added these lines to /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf:

```
root=myemail@gmail.com
mailhub=smtp.gmail:465
rewriteDomain=gmail.com
AuthUser=myemail@gmail.com
AuthPass=123456
FromLineOverride=YES
UseTLS=YES
```

Then I run the following:

```
ssmtp anothermail@gmail.com
To: anothermail@gmail.com
From: myemail@gmail.com
Subject: Some Email
Some more info
```

And I press ctrl+D and get this message:

```
ssmtp: Cannot open smtp.gmail:465
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mailhub` address is missing the `.com` TLD i.e.

```
mailhub=smtp.gmail:465
```

should be

```
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:465
```